# Not able to use namespace in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I am trying to develop a game in Unity editor.
I'm not able to use the namespace from one script into another.
Please find the scripts below.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    public static class CrossPlatformInputManager
    {
        public enum ActiveInputMethod
        {
            Hardware,
            Touch
        }


        private static VirtualInput activeInput;

        private static VirtualInput s_TouchInput;
        private static VirtualInput s_HardwareInput;
    }
}
```

AxisTouchButton.cs

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    public class AxisTouchButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
    {
        // designed to work in a pair with another axis touch button
        // (typically with one having -1 and one having 1 axisValues)
        public string axisName = "Horizontal"; // The name of the axis
        public float axisValue = 1; // The axis that the value has
        public float responseSpeed = 3; // The speed at which the axis touch button responds
        public float returnToCentreSpeed = 3; // The speed at which the button will return to its centre

        AxisTouchButton m_PairedWith; // Which button this one is paired with
        CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_Axis; // A reference to the virtual axis as it is in the cross platform input

        void OnEnable()
        {
            if (!CrossPlatformInputManager.AxisExists(axisName))
            {
                // if the axis doesnt exist create a new one in cross platform input
                m_Axis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(axisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_Axis);
            }
            else
            {
                m_Axis = CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxisReference(axisName);
            }
            FindPairedButton();
        }
    }
}
```

The script `CrossPlatformInputManager` has namespace `UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput`, but I'm not able to get that namespace in `AxisTouchButton.cs` in Unity Monodevelop editor.

P.S. : Both the files are located in different directory.

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with the namespace?

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

When your class already is in the namespace `UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput` you don´t need a `using`for that namespace. Simply remove the `using`-statement.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput; // remove this line
namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    public class AxisTouchButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This apllies to both sourcscode-files.

Btw.: having classes that belong into the same namespace should also be located in the same directory.

Comment: But will it fix OP's `I'm not able to use the namespace from one script into another.` problem?

Comment: @Stefan OP doesn´t need to *use* the namespace when he/she´s already *in* it.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But I am still wondering if that will result in OP's specific error. I must say, I don't have any experience with monodevelop so this is just out of curiosity. My guess would be that, although OP is using a redundant `using` directive, it wouldn't break access to the classes in the namespace. I am also wondering what OP means by `I'm not able to get that namespace in AxisTouchButton.cs in Unity Monodevelop editor`

Comment: I removed using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput; from both the scripts, but still the same error